# How can i write this regex inverted?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to search this string "Spelled [wurd]  Show IPA     noun  1.a "

and delete everything that is outside of the [ ] using:

```
String pron = noHTML.replaceAll("\\[.*?]","");  //(there is a double \\ \\ here...)
```

This replaces everything inside.. how to reverse it? :S

I have tried combinations of ! and ^ but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
String pron = noHTML.replaceAll("(^.*\\[)|(\\].*$)","");
```

To include brackets use *lookahead* and *lookbehind* -

```
String pron = noHTML.replaceAll("(^.*(?=\\[))|((?<=\\]).*$)","");
```

For more info on *lookahead* and *lookbehind*, refer http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: ahh aaa! closest yet! but i was hoping to keep the [ ]

Comment: Updated my answer to include that

Answer (score 3):

I'd simply replace the entire string with the part in the brackets:

```
String pron = noHTML.replaceAll(".*?\\[(.*?)\\].*", "$1");
```

This (1) matches the entire string, (2) captures the part in the brackets and stores it in the first capturing group and (3) uses that group as replacement for the entire matched string.

Including the brackets in the result is simply a matter or moving the `()` outward a bit:

```
String pron = noHTML.replaceAll(".*?(\\[.*?\\]).*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
String pron = noHTML.replaceAll("\[([^\[\]].*)\]","");
```

Here:

http://rubular.com/r/95ETge7Pyv